# Possible to Use Stored Function in Hibernate Where Clause?

Tags: hibernate, stored-procedures, where-clause

A quick hibernate question.  I have a stored function and I want to order my objects by it.  Is that possible without using raw sql?  Something effectively like:

```
createQuery("from SomeClass where some_proc(someProperty) > 5")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such SQL is beyond the scope of HQL, but you can have hibernate execute arbitrary SQL using [`createNativeQuery()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29):

```
SomeClass o = em.createNativeQuery("select * from SomeClassTable where some_proc(someProperty) > 5", SomeClass.class);
```

See [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/query_native.html) for more information on native queries.